# I have bad syntax I would like to know what my mistake is to pass it to mysql

Tags: mysql

```
 ALTER TABLE `EscolaresadeudosBiblioteca` 


ADD CONSTRAINT `DF_adeudosBiblioteca_adeudo` 


DEFAULT ((1)) FOR `adeudo`

GO
```

I'm new to mysql, I'm trying to move from sql to mysql. I would like to know where I am wrong to correct the rest

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Move from sql to mysql, only that I'm new and I don't know the syntax perfectly

Comment: SQL is a language, while MySQL is an engine. Do you mean "from SQL Server"?

Comment: @TheImpaler yes, it is from sql server

Answer (score 0):

`DEFAULT` is not a constraint but a property of a column. You can set it up as:

```
create table x1 (
  id int,
  status int
);

alter table x1 alter status set default 3;
```

See [Safari Online](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mysql-cookbook/0596001452/ch08s05.html).